# NuGet package manager listing non-existent packages

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I'm currently playing around with setting up a local NuGet package source - basically a shared folder on one of our servers. I added some packages to it the other day and they showed up fine in VS ("Manage NuGet Packages" dialog).

Today I realised I had screwed something up when I created the packages, so I deleted them off the server and added the correct ones (same package IDs but different version no's and package file names). However my VS dialog still lists the old packages. If I change "Sort by" from "Most Downloads" to a different option (e.g. "Published Date") then the new packages appear (along with the old ones that no longer exist).

I'm assuming this is due to some kind of caching. How can I stop the old packages from being listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I backed-up the old package files into a subfolder within the package source folder on the server. It seems that NuGet scans subfolders as well, and was picking up the contents of this backup folder. Now moved elsewhere and all is good!